# Filter on diffs made by specific author(s)

Tags: git, jgit

I would like to diff a file between 2 branches, and apply patch only for diffs from a specific author (Something like git blame diff?). I would need to do this for many files.

Basically, on IntelliJ, when I attempt to resolve conflicts in their merge tool window, I can select `annotate` that shows the authors for each of the lines, for which I can manually apply the non-conflicting and conflicting changes for an author from the other branch. I would like to do this programmatically.

I attempted to get commits made by specific authors using:

```sh
git log branch1..branch2 --author '\(author1\|author2)' --reverse --pretty=%H $file
```

and then

```sh
git cherry-pick -n --strategy=recursive -n $commit -X theirs
```

however `-X theirs` picks only commits from another branch in case of conflicts. I intend to pick non-conflicting diffs from other branch as well, but only for specific authors.

How do I achieve this?

I am using this script to run it for all files in a directory:

```
for file in ./directory/*; do
    fileNameWithExtension="${file##*/}"
    fileNameWithoutExtension="${fileNameWithExtension%.*}"
    git log branch1..branch2 --author '\(author1\|author2\)' --reverse --pretty=%H $file |
    while read commit; do
        git stash
        git cherry-pick -n --strategy=recursive -n $commit -X theirs
        git reset .
        git add $file
        git commit -m "Random commit to commit the changes: new updates for $fileNameWithExtension" || exit
    done
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. A `git cherry-pick` takes the entire commit, which may produce conflicts; adding `-X theirs` says to resolve low level conflicts by taking "theirs" (which really means index-slot-3), but that has no effect on the unconflicted changes, which *do* get taken.

Comment: So cherry-pick ideally should pick the non-conflicting diffs as well, however not sure why it won't do so successfully for all the files? I updated the description with the shell script I am running.

Comment: It should, yes. I'm not sure what the point of the `git stash` here is. The `git reset .` does a mixed reset: the target commit is `HEAD` so the branch name does not move, and the index gets filled in from the `HEAD` commit. The `git add $file` will copy the one file back into the index and the `git commit -m ...` should make a new snapshot from whatever is in the index at that point (though if the delta from the commit in question did not apply any changes for some reason, you'd have an "empty commit", i.e., the index would match `HEAD` and `git commit` would omit the commit entirely.

Comment: Right yeah, however I realized there are some caveats to this. If I cherry-pick commits from only author1/author2 from branch2, let's say author3 removed author1/author2's changes from branch1, then I'd need that to reflect that in the branch1, instead branch1 still has the old changes from author1/author2 (which were actually replaced by author3 in another old commit).

Comment: Is there no way to just compare the latest rev in both branches and pick all lines filtered on specific authors? Basically the way we manually use IntelliJ's git merge/diff tool to apply the non-conflicting/conflicting changes using ">>" or "<<"? Something like a `git blame diff` and apply patch filtered on specific authors.

Comment: There's no *easy* or *good* way to do that.